# CiviCRM API page not displaying in Drupal

Tags: drupal, api, developer

I am developing for Gsoc this year and i got up one day to use the API explorer but the page somewhat fails to load. below is a screen-shot of the display [image: API explorer page]

Comment: What Drupal theme are you using for your Civi interface?  If you try switching your Civi theme to something standard like Garland, does that change anything?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this once before and it was caused by a crash when fetching the list of entities. Do you have any custom code in place that defines a new entity? Try turning on debug & backtrace and run this from the civicrm home page in your browser console:

```
CRM.api3('entity', 'get')
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you have a Javascript blocker add-on in your browser? You should whitelist that site allowing Javascript and then it should show up normally.